# summarize data.table in R - sum certain columns maintain information on others - speed up performance

Tags: r, performance, data.table, summary

I have a fairly large data.table in R. The operation should be performed for every MY_BY value. I'd like to sum certain variables given in a vector variable "my_sum_vars" and maintain others based on the appearance of MY_KEY. If MY_KEY == 1 is available i'd like to get the values of this row, otherwise just of any other. (in my example the first one)

Please note that there are many more columns. this should only explain my problem.

The data.table has many rows and i don't understand why this approach is not more performant than a split and merge approach.

Any Idea to speed up the code?

Thanks!

```
library(data.table)

my_data <- data.table(MY_NUM1 = 1:10,
                      MY_NUM2 = 11:20,
                      MY_CHAR1 = LETTERS[1:10],
                      MY_CHAR2 = LETTERS[11:20],
                      MY_KEY = c(rep(1:2,3), 2:3, 3:4),
                      MY_BY  = rep(letters[1:5], each = 2))

my_sum_vars <- c("MY_NUM1", "MY_NUM2")
my_by <- c("MY_BY")

getKeyOrFirst <- function(my_subset){
  ret <- my_subset[MY_KEY == 1]
  if(nrow(ret) == 0){
    ret <- my_subset[1]
  }
  return(ret)
}

my_summary <- my_data[, c(getKeyOrFirst(.SD[, setdiff(names(my_data), c(my_sum_vars, my_by)), with = FALSE]),
            lapply(.SD[, my_sum_vars, with = FALSE], sum)),
        by = my_by]
```

I already tried to split the code in two steps. perform the sum and selection separately. but then i got the data multiple times in my memory and the should be in my opinion a smarter data.table way.

Output:

```
> my_data
    MY_NUM1 MY_NUM2 MY_CHAR1 MY_CHAR2 MY_KEY MY_BY
 1:       1      11        A        K      1     a
 2:       2      12        B        L      2     a
 3:       3      13        C        M      1     b
 4:       4      14        D        N      2     b
 5:       5      15        E        O      1     c
 6:       6      16        F        P      2     c
 7:       7      17        G        Q      2     d
 8:       8      18        H        R      3     d
 9:       9      19        I        S      3     e
10:      10      20        J        T      4     e
> my_summary
   MY_BY MY_CHAR1 MY_CHAR2 MY_KEY MY_NUM1 MY_NUM2
1:     a        A        K      1       3      23
2:     b        C        M      1       7      27
3:     c        E        O      1      11      31
4:     d        G        Q      2      15      35
5:     e        I        S      3      19      39
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a `data.table` solution, but using `dplyr` you can simply group your data by each value in "BY_MY" and then sum the columns of interest:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>% 
  group_by(MY_BY) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("MY_NUM"), sum, .names = "sum_{.col}"))

# # A tibble: 5 × 3
# MY_BY sum_MY_NUM1 sum_MY_NUM2
# <chr>       <int>       <int>
# 1 a               3          23
# 2 b               7          27
# 3 c              11          31
# 4 d              15          35
# 5 e              19          39
```

Note this does not return the `head()` values for each group for the "MY_CHAR1" and "MY_CHAR2" variables or the sum of "MY_KEY". From looking at your data I've assumed it does not make sense to  do so. Let me know if this is incorrect.

In reference to your comment regarding speeding up the process, `dplyr` scales nicely. On this dataset with one million rows that was modelled loosely on your example:

```
set.seed(1)
my_data <- data.table(MY_NUM1 = sample(1:10, 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                      MY_NUM2 = sample(11:20, 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                      MY_CHAR1 = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                      MY_CHAR2 = sample(LETTERS[11:20], 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                      MY_KEY = sample(1:4, 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                      MY_BY = sample(letters, 1000000, replace = TRUE))

my_data %>% 
  group_by(MY_BY) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("MY_NUM"), sum, .names = "sum_{.col}"))
```

the result was returned in ~0.084 seconds on a very average Win10 machine with 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the operations should be efficient, also doesn't necessarily have a bigger memory footprint since it operates by reference. This gets the desired result, taking the first row of columns `cols2`.

```
library(data.table)

cols1 <- grep("NUM", colnames(my_data))
cols2 <- grep("CHAR|KEY", colnames(my_data))

cbind(my_data[, lapply(.SD, first), by = MY_BY, .SDcols = cols2],
      my_data[, lapply(.SD, sum),by = MY_BY, .SDcols = cols1][, MY_BY := NULL])
   MY_BY MY_CHAR1 MY_CHAR2 MY_KEY MY_NUM1 MY_NUM2
1:     a        A        K      1       3      23
2:     b        C        M      1       7      27
3:     c        E        O      1      11      31
4:     d        G        Q      2      15      35
5:     e        I        S      3      19      39
```

If you wanted to get a dynamic row from `cols2`, e.g. the number `MY_KEY` of the first row

```
library(data.table)

cols1 <- grep("NUM", colnames(my_data))
cols2 <- grep("CHAR|KEY", colnames(my_data))

cbind(my_data[, lapply(.SD, "[", sort(MY_KEY)[1]), by = MY_BY, .SDcols = cols2],
      my_data[, lapply(.SD, sum),by = MY_BY, .SDcols = cols1][, MY_BY := NULL])
   MY_BY MY_CHAR1 MY_CHAR2 MY_KEY MY_NUM1 MY_NUM2
1:     a        A        K      1       3      23
2:     b        C        M      1       7      27
3:     c        E        O      1      11      31
4:     d        H        R      3      15      35
5:     e     <NA>     <NA>     NA      19      39
```